# Example of Category, covariant functors

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra

This example was given by my professor:

-The category $F(Q, \mathrm{Vec}_K)$ of covariant functors from $Q$ to ${\rm Vec}_K$, with morphisms being natural transformations is a **well-defined** category.
Here $Q$ denotes a path category of a quiver (i.e. the objects in $Q$ are the vertices of a quiver, the mosphisms from $i$ in $q_0$ to $j$ in $q_0$ are the path from $i$ to $j$, and the composition is given by the concatenation of paths.
For a $K$ field, $\mathrm{Vec}_K$ is the category of vector spaces over $K$.

Why is this a **well-defined category**? How can I prove it?

Furthermore, my book says $F(Q, \mathrm{Vec}_K)$ is **equivalent to the category** $(\mathrm{Rep}_K\, Q)$ of K-linear representations of $Q$. Why? How to show this?

Comment: This is not actually anything special about the categories involved (well, the first part). It works for any two categories, and it is just a matter of checking things. For the second one, how have you defined representations of a quiver?

Comment: Why does this ask for well-defined (as opposed to defined or just "is a category")? The term "well-defined" is usually only used for cases where a definition *a priori* depends on some choice made but turns out to actually not depend on that choice. And I don't see any choices made here ...

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, I interpret it as asking why $F(Q,Vect_K)$ is a category.

As Tobias Kildetoft mentioned in his comment, this is a general construction, namely, for any pair of categories $A$ and $B$, with $A$ a small category, we can define the functor category $F(A,B)$:

- its objects are functors $F:A\to B$
- for any pair of objects $F$ and $G$, the set of morphisms from $F$ to $G$ consists of all natural transformations $\alpha:F\Rightarrow G$.

To see why this is a category, note that for any triple of functors $F,G,H:A\to B$ and any pair of natural transformations $\alpha:F\Rightarrow G$ and $\beta: G\Rightarrow H$ we can define a natural transformation $\beta\circ \alpha:F\Rightarrow H$ by setting $(\beta\circ \alpha)(a):=\beta(a)\circ \alpha(a)$ for every object $a$ of $A$. The fact that this is a natural transformation follows from $\alpha$ and $\beta$ being natural transformations (write down the diagrams!).  For every functor $F$ there is the identity natural transformation $1_F:F\Rightarrow F$ which is given by $1_F(a):=1_{F(a)}$ for every object $a$.
Associativity and unitality for this composition follow from associativity and unitality for composition of morphisms in $B$.

For your second question, I am going to assume that the definition of the category $(Rep_KQ)$ is the usual one, namely:

- objects are given by pairs $(V,\phi)$ where $V$ is a collection of vector spaces $\{V_i\}_{i\in I}$ with $I$ the set of vertices of the quiver, and $\phi$ is a collection of linear maps $\{\phi_{i,j}:V_i\to V_j\}_{(i,j)\in E}$ with $E$ the set of directed edges of the quiver.
- a morphism $f:(V,\phi)\to (V',\phi')$ is given by a collection of linear maps $\{f_i:V_i\to V'_i\}_{i\in I}$ such that for any $(i,j)\in E$ we have $\phi'_{i,j}\circ f_i=f_j\circ \phi_{i,j}$.

Now, this category not only is equivalent to the category $F(Q,Vect_K)$, it is *isomorphic* to it. To see why, you just have to unfold what it means to have a functor $F:Q\to Vect_K$, or a natural transformation $F\Rightarrow G$ for $F,G:Q\to Vect_K$.